# Reading embedding XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, embed

I'm trying to read an XML file that is an embedded resource and use it to create a `DataSet`.

Normally I would access an xml file as follows...

```
    'THIS SECTION POPULTATES THE DATAGRIDVIEW WITH STOCK INFORMATION MADE AVAILABLE IN THE XML DOCUMENT (Stock.xml)...
    Dim filepath As String = (IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Stock.xml")
    Dim DS_CUSTOMERS As New DataSet
    DS_CUSTOMERS.ReadXml(filepath)

    Dim DS_CUSTOMERS As New DataSet
    DS_CUSTOMERS.ReadXml(rm123.GetObject("Stock.xml"))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS.Tables(0)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Data"
```

Referencing embedded images is also easy. This is done as follows (Combobox supplies the file name in this case):

```
    'This loads the embeded recource image...
    Dim rm As Resources.ResourceManager
    rm = New Resources.ResourceManager("Load_Calculator.resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
    PictureBox1.Image = rm.GetObject(ComboBox1.Text)
```

Now my logic (which is wrong) would be to make a hybrid of the two codes and do the following but when debugging I get nothing.

```
'THIS SECTION POPULTATES THE DATAGRIDVIEW WITH STOCK INFORMATION MADE AVAILABLE IN THE XML DOCUMENT (Stock.xml)...
Dim rm123 As Resources.ResourceManager
rm123 = New Resources.ResourceManager("Load_Calculator.resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)

Dim DS_CUSTOMERS As New DataSet
DS_CUSTOMERS.ReadXml(rm123.GetObject("Stock.xml"))


DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS.Tables(0)
DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Data"
```

and the xml file as follows:

```
    <COMPELATION>
    <Data>
            <TTN>Select a Truss-System...</TTN>
            <FJQ></FJQ>
            <TTH></TTH>
            <TTW></TTW>
            <FCT></FCT>
            <MTD></MTD>
            <MTT></MTT>
            <DVB></DVB>
            <TVB></TVB>
            <DTP></DTP>
            <MAT></MAT>
            <TSW></TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FD33</TTN>
            <FJQ>3x</FJQ>
            <TTH>257,85 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>2 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,044 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FD34</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>290 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>2 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,058 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>HD33</TTN>
            <FJQ>3x</FJQ>
            <TTH>257,85 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,055 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>HD34</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>290 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,074 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>HD33</TTN>
            <FJQ>3x</FJQ>
            <TTH>257,85 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,055 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>HD34</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>290 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>20 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,074 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FD44</TTN>
            <FJQ>3x</FJQ>
            <TTH>400 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>400 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>2 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>25 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,075 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FD43</TTN>
            <FJQ>3x</FJQ>
            <TTH>353,11 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>400 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>25 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,059 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>HD44</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>400 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>400 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>25 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>2 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>12 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,081 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>XD</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>400 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>290 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC2-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>3 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>25 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,085 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>ST</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>500 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>500 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC3-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>4 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>30 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,134 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FT50</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>521,10 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>570 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC3-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>4 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>25 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,135 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>XT</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>800 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>570 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>CS3-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>50 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>4 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>40 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,200 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>TT</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>1010 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>580 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>SC3-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>60 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>5 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>50 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,250 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>FT100</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>986 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>580 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>CS3-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>60 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>5 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>50 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,220 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
            <TTN>MT</TTN>
            <FJQ>4x</FJQ>
            <TTH>1180 mm</TTH>
            <TTW>780 mm</TTW>
            <FCT>CS4-CON</FCT>
            <MTD>60 mm</MTD>
            <MTT>5 mm</MTT>
            <DVB>50 mm</DVB>
            <TVB>3 mm</TVB>
            <DTP>16 mm</DTP>
            <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
            <TSW>0,220 kN/m</TSW>
    </Data>
 </COMPELATION>

<!-- TTN= Truss Type Name -->
<!-- FJQ= Face Joist Quantity -->
<!-- TTH= Total Truss Hight -->
<!-- TTW= Total Truss Width -->
<!-- MTD= Main Tube Diameter -->
<!-- FCT= Fiting/ Connection Type -->
<!-- MTT= Main Tube Thickness -->
<!-- DVB= Diameter Vertical Brace -->
<!-- TVB= Thickness Vertical Brace -->
<!-- DTP= Diameter Truss Pin -->
<!-- MAT= Material Type -->
<!-- TSW= Truss Self Weight -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetManifestResourceStream` method (instead of `GetObject`) to create a `Stream` from the embedded resource. Then you can read it using the overload of `DataSet.ReadXml` that takes a `Stream` as its argument.

```
Dim DS_CUSTOMERS As New DataSet
Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
Using rs As IO.Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName.Name & ".Stock.xml")
    DS_CUSTOMERS.ReadXml(rs)
End Using
DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS.Tables(0)
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Data"
```

To add an existing XML file to your project as an embedded resource, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose Add | Existing item ... Then in the Add existing item dialog, navigate to the Stock.xml file (you may need to set the file type filter to "Data files") and double-click on the file to add a copy of it to your project. Finally, click on the file in Solution Explorer to display the properties, and change the Build Action property to "Embedded Resource".

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT I tested the code in my answer and verified that the DataSet has one table, which would be Table(0). Could there be something wrong with your XML file? What statement generates that error?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions. I'm guessing that you get that error on a statement following the code that I posted and that looks something like `DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_CUSTOMERS.Tables(0)`. I tested that statement and it runs without getting an exception. I'll edit my answer to include it. I believe that there is either a problem with your XML file, or the code you are using is not the same as mine.

Comment: Well beats me, I keep getting the error... see my original post for updated info qua type of xml filr used mabey theres somthing not correct with that type of format

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT I replaced my dummy Stock.xml with the data you edited into your question, and still I get no error with the code that I posted. Note that the code in your question sets the `DataSource` property twice (the second overwrites the first), but that doesn't cause this error. Again, I can only assume that the code you are using is not the same as the code in my answer.

Comment: and cause im now unsure the file recurce is added as "Files" als it has no xml extention an the properties pain says its a textfile is this correct?

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT I have edited my answer to include information on how to add an XML file as an Embedded Resource.

Comment: Hi I have almost given up on this question except for the fact that I need to complete this for work for some reason im not getting it embedded is there an area i can upload my project to so that soemone can check whats going on?

Comment: i think it has to do with the following section of code             Dim DS_CUSTOMERS As New DataSet
            Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
            Using rs As IO.Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName.Name & ".Stock.xml")
                DS_CUSTOMERS.ReadXml(rs)

                Dim dvdonors As DataView = DS_CUSTOMERS.Tables(0).DefaultView
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dvdonors

                dvdonors.RowFilter = "TTN = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'" 'works compleate match
            End Using